# How do I launch a unit test on a Visual Studio Test Agent?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

We have multiple servers we'd like to be able to run unit tests on. We use Visual Studio Community 2017 for the unit test development.

We think that Visual Studio Test Controllers and Visual Studio Test Agents might be the best option to do this. The eventual goal is to have our VS Test Controller installed on one server and the VS Test Agents installed on several other servers; the VS Test Controller will then launch these unit tests on the VS Test Agents.

Before taking that leap, I'm trying to test all of this locally. I've installed both a VS Test Controller and VS Test Agent (both 2017) on my desktop PC. I've successfully registered the Test Agent with the Test Controller and when I log in to Windows I see a "Test Agent Status" window that looks like the Agent is waiting for instructions. (Image below.)

[Visual Studio Test Agent 2017: "Test Agent Status" window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOVVR.png)

I also have my VS IDE setup with a .testsettings file. I've pointed it at my local Test Controller (127.0.0.1:6901) from the 'Roles' tab of the .testsettings configuration wizard and I can see the registered agent with a status of "Ready". There is an icon in this 'Roles' tab which, when moused over, says "Connected to '127.0.0.1:6901'".

So far, so good.

I've found the "[How to: Run a Test Using Test Controllers and Test Agents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182638.aspx)" article on the MSDN. Having followed the steps outlined here (namely choosing the "Active Load and Web Test Settings" context-menu option on the .testsettings file and running one of my unit tests from the Test Explorer), the test just runs normally i.e. it doesn't actually run on the Test Agent. I know this because the aforementioned "Test Agent Status" window doesn't change; the "Currently running test" stays as "None".

**How do I run a unit test from Visual Studio so that it executes on the specified Test Agent via the Test Controller?**